# Proper use of RealmRecyclerViewAdapyter

Tags: java, android, realm

Is there a documentation of the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter (other than the code itself - following the link given below)?

In [the example](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview/MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java) I found only this adapter declaration.

Comment: Is there something specific that you would like to know, about the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.  That example should work, pretty much, right out of the box...

Comment: Yes, it is a nice example, but I was looking for a complete documentation of the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: My apologies, the JavaDoc for the two adapters is not up yet.  We are working to get them published now.  In the main time, as @Sergey says below, our Adapter is pretty straightforward.  Give it a try. If you have any specific questions, ask them hear and pop the Realm tag on them.  We'll get right back to you.

Answer (score 0):

All about realm you can found (also interesting things of realm for Android platform) in [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#working-with-android).

All documentation about [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#working-with-android) it is an [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview/MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java), which you found.

Extrapolate your knowledges from `RecyclerViewAdapter` to `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` and be creative - You will succeed! :)